Will there be Sanhedrin in Messianic Times?
Following my back-and-forth with @RabbiKaii I suddenly realized that the reinstitution of a functioning Sanherdin is not mentioned in Rambam's vision of the Messianic times (Hil. Melachim 11.1 and on).

"הַמֶּלֶךְ הַמָּשִׁיחַ עָתִיד לַעֲמֹד וּלְהַחְזִיר מַלכוּת דָּוִד לְיָשְׁנָהּ לַמֶּמְשָׁלָה הָרִאשׁוֹנָה. וּבוֹנֶה הַמִּקְדָּשׁ וּמְקַבֵּץ נִדְחֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל. וְחוֹזְרִין כָּל הַמִּשְׁפָּטִים בְּיָמָיו כְּשֶׁהָיוּ מִקֹּדֶם. מַקְרִיבִין קָרְבָּנוֹת."

I assume many would argue that it is included in "וְחוֹזְרִין כָּל הַמִּשְׁפָּטִים", but one might object that the Sanhedrin would be obsolete, as there would be no Bad Inclination, no sin, and the Messiah as a prophet will singlehandedly establish the new "Jewish world order".
No human rabbi could possibly object to him after he successfully fulfills all prophecies and builds a functioning Temple, so the Sanhedrin would be completely unnecessary.
So which one is that: "business as usual", or "no Sanhedrin necessary" 1) according to Rambam elsewhere and 2) according to additional views?

The Sanhedrin was not only a "legislative" body. It also had judicial (e.g. trying a kohen gadol), executive (e.g. declaring milchemet reshut) and ritual (e.g. sanctifying extensions to the Temple Mount) functions.

Does the Rambam say there'll be no Bad Inclination and no sin?

@shmosel the Torah says.

@Al Berko: please refer to this answer quoting the Lubavitcher Rebbe.

@JoelK Yes but that was in previous reality. it doesn't have to translate into Messianic times, because the Messiah has absolute monarchic power.

"Absolute monarchic power" still doesn't give him the authority to extend the Temple Mount, for example, so at least on that score @JoelK's point is still valid. But anyway, Moshiach himself would have to be appointed by the Sanhedrin (see my comment on Shalom's answer).

the purpose of the Sanhedrin is to decide Jewish law which is going to be required regardless of whether anyone has a yetzer hara or not. Having a king does not negate the need for a legislative body that decides the halacha.

Rambam actually writes it pretty explicitly in his commentary to Sanhedrin 1:3 that it is a prerequisite for Messianic times. (Thus he doesn't list it as a requirement for the Messiah per se to perform.) He doesn't spell this out in his code (the Yad), but the Yad does say in Sanhedrin that he reasons there must be a way to reboot real Semicha; as his reasoning for it appears in the commentary to the Mishnah, it's pretty reasonable to assume that he didn't retract from that reasoning.

ויראה לי כי כשתהי' הסכמה מכל החכמים והתלמידים להקדים עליהם איש מן
הישיבה וישימו אותו לראש ובלבד שיהא זה בא"י כמו שזכרנו הנה האיש ההוא
תתקיים לו הישיבה ויהיה סמוך ויסמוך הוא אחר כן מי שירצה שאם לא תאמר כן
אי אפשר שתמצא ב"ד הגדול לעולם לפי שנצטרך שיהיה כל אחד מהם סמוך על כל
פנים והקב"ה יעד שישובו כמו שנאמר ואשיבה שופטיך כבראשונה ויועציך כבתחלה
אחרי כן יקרא לך עיר הצדק וזה יהיה בלא ספק כשיכון הבורא יתברך לבות בני
אדם ותרבה זכותם ותשוקתם לשם יתברך ולתורה ותגדל חכמתם לפני בא המשיח כמו
שיתבאר זה בפסוקים הרבה במקרא.
It appears to me that if an agreement from all scholars and students is reached to promote one man as head, if done in the Land of Israel,
... that fellow shall be samuch, and can grant semicha to others.
As if we do not say this, it will forever be impossible to find a Great
Court, as it requires all of their individuals to be samuch; yet
HKB"H testified that they shall return, as Isaiah writes -- I shall
return your judges as before, and your advisors as originally, and
then you shall be called the City of Righteousness; and this will
undoubtedly happen when G-d will establish the hearts of people, and
they will have many merits and desire for G-d and the Torah and have
great wisdom, before the coming of the Messiah, as is explained in
numerous verses in Scripture.


+1 Thank you. IIRC this was the ruling/interpretation that the nascent Sanhedrin tried to base their authority in 2004. How do you reconcile that with Hil. Melachim? At what stage does the establishment of the Sanhedrin take place?

@AlBerko Rambam (Hil. Sanhedrin 14:12, based on Rosh Hashanah 31b) says that they'll first be re-established in Tiberias and then move to Jerusalem. Which is another reason he didn't have to mention its re-establishment in Hil. Melachim, having already stated that this will take place. Furthermore, he says at the beginning of Melachim (1:3) that a king can be appointed only by the national Sanhedrin, so necessarily "the King Moshiach" (11:1) has to find them already functioning in order to be that.

I see it says "וְקַבָּלָה הִיא שֶׁבִּטְבֶרְיָא עֲתִידִין לַחְזֹר תְּחִלָּה וּמִשָּׁם נֶעֱתָקִין לַמִּקְדָּשׁ" So the Temple is already erected. 2. I understand you make 1+1=2 but regarding the Messiah, didn't he conclude that it is impossible to know? Anyway, the establishment of the Sanhedrin is definitely missing from his depiction of the era.

@AlBerko Sure, eventually they'll be in the Beis Hamikdash, since that's where their headquarters are supposed to be. Doesn't mean that they'll already be there when they anoint Moshiach; maybe they'll do that while they're still in Tiberias. || When Rambam says that "it is impossible to know," he's talking about certain other details, such as whether Eliyahu will come to pre-announce Moshiach's coming. The details that we do know include that as a king, he'll have to be appointed by them. || The Rambam regularly relies on details he's given before; that's a known rule among the posekim.
